# Generating packages with the selective controllers in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core-webapi

Situation:Need to have solution with multiple controllers in my web api project of asp.net core 2.1 based upon business logic. This project will be endpoints for multiple countries.There will be core controllers and county wise controllers in this project. For e.g. core_customer which serves all the country customer and other will be like signapore_account which will be end points to only singapore location.

Problem: Have to deploy this project on different instances in multiple countries.For e.g same code will be deployed on Singapore,Malaysia etc... 
Looking for a packaging solution where we can deploy this project content based upon some configuration. For e.g. core_customer and singapore_account will be deployed on singapore instance and core_customer should be deployed only on Malaysia instance.
Basically looking for packaging (MSBUILD tool) which can publish the code based upon the controllers by reading some config file. Is it possible to have this kind of packaging mechanism or is any alternate way to do this.

High level scenario. 
there are 3 controllers  c1,c2,c3 ---c1 is core(common) , c2(serves Singapore) and c3(serves Malaysia).
While deploying the proj,have to deploy c1 and c2 on singapore instance
and c1 and c3 on Malaysia instance.

Comment: Create a class library for your common controllers and then a separate app for each country, which references this. Then, you can easily deploy whichever app to whichever country it belongs to. If you need to share views, static resources, etc., you can take it farther and create a Razor Class Library instead to house all the common stuff, and then reference that from each country-specific app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there any possibility if can use same APP for all the countries and my build management take care of the controllers needed for that specific countries.

Comment: No. But, you really don't want that anyways. Having a project per country lets you do automated builds and deployments easily per country, and with a RCL backing them, you likely wouldn't need much specific code per project. Your RCL would basically be you "app", it just wouldn't run on its own.

Comment: i understood about the segregation which you are talking about but my scenario would be like feature needed from the "core"+"Country wise"  APi's. So if go with the different app then have to repeat my code of core in all the app's which i am not eager too.Correct me if my understanding is wrong here.Also, view here would be angular and we are building web api in core 2.1.Not using full mvc approach here.